# SLF4J Initialization - Substitute Loggers

Tags: scala, logging, slf4j, logback, race-condition

I am doing a project in Scala and I am using slf4j with Logback for logging. Now, logging initialization does not seem to be thread-safe. As a solution, slf4j is creating substitute loggers, i.e., NoOp-loggers, that swallow log statements made during initialization. [The slf4j homepage](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html) states on this matter:

> Substitute loggers were created during the default configuration phase of the underlying logging system
>
> Highly configurable logging systems such as logback and log4j may create components which invoke loggers during their own initialization. See issue LOGBACK-127 for a typical occurrence. However, since the binding process with SLF4J has not yet completed (because the underlying logging system was not yet completely loaded into memory), it is not possible to honor such logger creation requests.
>
> To avoid this chicken-and-egg problem, SLF4J creates substitute loggers during this phase (initialization). Calls made to the substitute loggers during this phase are simply dropped. After the initialization completes, the substitute logger will delegate logging calls to the appropriate logger implementation and otherwise will function as any other logger returned by LoggerFactory.
>
> If any substitute logger had to be created, SLF4J will emit a a listing of such loggers. This list is intended to let you know that any logging calls made to these loggers during initialization have been dropped.

There is also a yet unresolved [issue](http://bugzilla.slf4j.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176) describing the problem.

For me, the problem occurred when I was testing how parts of the application work together. Log statements of a producer, running in its own thread were lost because they were sent to a substitute logger. Adding a log statement just before creating the producer thread seemed to help initializing the logger in time. However, I would like to know whether an arbitrary call to LoggerFactory.getLogger as a first statement in the application guarantees that I will never log to a substitute logger.

In short, my questions are:

- Does LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[A]) instantiate all loggers, or could it be that two later, concurrent calls to LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[B]) will yield one substitute logger?
- Is there a way to obtain a guarantee, i.e., to check, that a logger has been initialized (I cannot check the type of the logger, since it is hidden by the slf4j facade) **Edit**: Actually, I just figured that I might be able to check the type of the logger. Could the following thoughts lead to a useful solution?:

  ```
  def logger(context: Class[_]) = {
    log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(context)
    if (log.isInstanceOf[SubstituteLogger]) logger(context) else log
  ```

  The problem I see with this approach is that it depends on one implementation specific class, i.e., <s>NOPLogger</s> SubstituteLogger.

**Addendum**: 
I am not sure if this is of relevance to this question, but I am wrapping the slf4j logger in a class which is instantiated for each logging context (context = the class that is calling the logger). Also, there is an object that creates instances of this wrapper, which is passed as an implicit constructor argument to each class that wants to do logging. I pass the logger as an argument rather than logging to a static object (or mixing in a trait) to enable passing a special logger in the unit tests.

Comment: Just got this using Akka... It was because the logger initialization was made several time concurrently (first time accessing a logger). So adding a dummy log at app startup fixed it.

Comment: I've hit the same problem with scalatest parallel testing. Since it's not latency-sensitive, I've fixed with a sleep and retry when `log` is a SubstituteLogger

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem because multiple dependencies brought along their own duplicate copies of the NoOp Logger. The solution, in my case was to explicitly the inhereted depencency on `slf4j-log4j12` via:

```
libraryDependencies = Seq(
  ...
  ).map(_.exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12" ))
```